# SQL cannot insert variable into XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

i have a database that have table Date with a xml Column that is initialise with a default xml data

```
<data>

</data>
```

I am trying to insert into that  XML column using variable

```
DECLARE @UserID INT;
SET @UserID = 10    

DECLARE @DataXML XML;
SET @DataXML = (SELECT TOP 1 d.DataXML 
                FROM [Data] AS d
                WHERE d.UserID = @UserID
                ORDER BY d.LastUpdate DESC );
SELECT @DataXML

DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @Data = '<point>15</point>'

DECLARE @XmlQuery NVARCHAR(max) 
SET @XmlQuery = 'insert ' + @Data + ' as last into (/data)[1]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) 
SET @sql='set @DataXML.modify('''+ @XmlQuery + ''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql , N'@DataXML XML OUT', @DataXML OUT

SELECT @DataXML
```

it update the variable which have the cell bud it didn't update the column

Can you anyone help me in this?

i am using SQL server 2012

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: You are only modifying the variable. You have update your table with the variable or modify the column in the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- Setup data...
create table dbo.Data (
  DataID int,
  DataXML xml,
  UserID int,
  LastUpdate datetime
);
insert dbo.Data (DataID, DataXML, UserID, LastUpdate)
values
  (1, N'<data></data>', 10, datetimefromparts(2014, 3, 7, 18, 21, 0, 0)),
  (2, N'<data></data>', 10, datetimefromparts(2014, 3, 7, 18, 22, 0, 0));

-- Find row ID...
declare @UserID int = 10;
declare @DataID int = (
  select top 1 DataID
  from dbo.Data
  where UserID = @UserID
  order by LastUpdate desc
);

-- Update row...
declare @Point int = 15;
update dbo.Data
set DataXML.modify(N' insert <point>{sql:variable("@Point")}</point> into (/data)[1] ')
where DataID = @DataID;

-- Result...
select * from dbo.Data;
```

| DataID | DataXML | UserID | LastUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <data /> | 10 | 2014-03-07 18:21:00.000 |
| 2 | <data><point>15</point></data> | 10 | 2014-03-07 18:22:00.000 |